# How do you display error message from firebase into an angular2 application

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, angular2-forms

How do I display error message in my application as oppose to printing in the console.
This is an example below (printing in console)

```
promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

I want to be able to print the above in my html.

Any help?

Comment: assigning value to variable not working?

Comment: I have tried that so many times and it is  not just working. Any other idea you think?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SydneyLoteria why did you delete it?

Comment: Here is what i tried:                                                   promise.catch(function(error){
            this.one = error.message;
        });

Comment: have you tried with an arrowfunction like,  `promise.catch((error)=>{ this.one = error.message; });`

Comment: yeah thank you...that worked.

Comment: Posted answer for future readers. you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **AarrowFunction** `()=>` as shown,

```
promise.catch((error)=>{ this.one = error.message; });
```